# Need to feed the input data for particular API in the collection using POSTMAN

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, api-testing, postman

Currently, am using POSTMAN collection for API testing. In the collection, we have more than 10 API's request. we are passing the input from the CSV while passing the input, I need to apply for only particular API, not for all API's. Let me know if there is any way to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a "data driven test" whereby you call the same service over and over with slightly different parameters in your payload.

E.g a findUser service, which you might call a hundred times using a csv of user names to test.

Danny Dainton (sorry, I don't know how to link him) has written a series of tutorials for Postman which you might want to read through.

Link -> [Danny Dainton's Postman articles](https://github.com/DannyDainton/All-Things-Postman)